# GUI Program for Documentations

Tags: windows, app

I’m searching for a GUI tool I found a year ago for writing documentations that you can sync with a Git repository. It was at least available for
Windows and I think macOS but forgot how it was called.

The GUI was in dark mode, on the left side when you had a repository opened was the file tree where you could create folders and md files.

Maybe someone here has a clue what it was called. I already searched on alternativeto.net but had so far no success finding it.

Thanks

Comment: What about VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

[Markdown Monster](https://markdownmonster.west-wind.com/) perhaps? It matches your not to specific description at least, as it's targetted at MD files, has a sidebar, [git integration](https://markdownmonster.west-wind.com/docs/_4xp0yygt2.htm) and it's in dark mode by default.